# How to make screen scrollable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flexible text widget at the top of screen in which will be some text that may be really big. If text in it become really big user might scroll the screen down to find other widgets on this screen

Right now if text become big my other widgets will move down, but screen will be same size

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll page in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765092/how-to-scroll-page-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrape your text with SingleChildScrollView
and then add this line

```
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```