# scroll page up and down

Tags: flutter

I am developing my first app in flutter that shows user's progress on exercise and food intake. Since there's a good deal of information needed to show, and it will not have enough space to show all information in a page. I am thinking to add a **Scrollbar()** widget to the body(). However,
it seems it does not work that I am not able to scroll the page up and down. Is there a way to do so (the app in not with ListView)?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765092/how-to-scroll-page-in-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use SingleChildScrollView.
as an example

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(children:[]));
```